# What is the meaning of "both" in D. Defoe's text?

Tags: word-usage

Does the word "both" in this fragment of D. Defoe's text relate to the verbs? Or does it mean that there were two actors who both suffered the same fate?

> Those whose avarice, prevailing over their honesty, had invaded the property of this book by a corrupt abridgment, have both failed in their hope and been ashamed of the fact.

Answer (score 1):

The 'both' refers to the two phrases which follow:

- failed in their hope
- been ashamed of the fact

We know that 'both' doesn't apply to the subjects 'those' because it is a generalisation, not two people that 'both' would usually imply.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! We say 'thanks' here by voting and 'accepting' answers. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help)?

Answer (score 1):

The 'both' refers to these two things:

- having failed in their hope
- being ashamed of the fact (of having failed in the hope)

I wonder if property is 'proper-ty' and might really mean 'propriety' or correctness, here.

Comment: Gosh weather vane we're thinking in synch

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I thought.

Comment: Yes, though I hadn't read it, which is what I'm saying. Even the same format...

Comment: According to the new edition I'm looking at, it is "property".

Comment: You're welcome, Tatiana.

Comment: Yes I looked it up, saw many versions with 'property'. But wondered if 'property' had a different earlier meaning, of 'being proper', or that it was a typo in Defoe's original. Because it does make much more sense, like that...

Comment: @Jelila, I think it makes sense as the author is indignant about the fact that the book was previously severely abridged, as if "deprived" of its property, speaking metaphorically.

Comment: @TatianaKuznetsova The passage goes on to say "shifting off the guilt, as well as they could, though weakly, from one another". Again, the action of people.

Comment: @BillJ Yes, I totally get the fact that people are meant.

Comment: @TatianaKuznetsova Nevertheless, I think "both" refers to "failed in their hope and been ashamed of the fact".

Comment: @BillJ yes, I agree. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, quite probably, @Tatiana Kuznetsova